# NullPointerException Android when calling a method in onCreate,

Tags: android

i created a method that gives me back a Cursor object, i try to use it for populating a listview, when i call the method in onCreate or in a button click it gives me NullPointerException.
The table is created, i tried to populate it through the interface before i created the Cursor function and is working, i can't understand why it gives me this error, i verified the views and the intent sender to this class, only when i use that method throws me this exception

```
 06-01 18:30:43.361    3430-3430/com.example.george.myfirstaplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.george.myfirstaplication/com.example.george.myfirstaplication.Genoflexiuni}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
        at `enter code here`android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.george.myfirstaplication.Genoflexiuni.populateListView(Genoflexiuni.java:88)
        at com.example.george.myfirstaplication.Genoflexiuni.onCreate(Genoflexiuni.java:62)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
```

This is the method

```
    public Cursor getAllGenoflexiuni(){

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {DataBaseHelper.DATE_TIME, DataBaseHelper.GREUTATE_EXERCITIU, DataBaseHelper.NUMBER_SETURI, DataBaseHelper.NUMBER_REPETITIONS};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(DataBaseHelper.GENOFLEXIUNI_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

here i want to use it

```
private String geDateTime(){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);

}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.genoflexiuni);
    weightText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightText);
    setsText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.setsText);
    repetitionsText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.repetitionsText);
    insertButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.insertButton);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listElemente);
    populateListView();


    insertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String weight = weightText.getText().toString();
            String sets = setsText.getText().toString();
            String repetitions = repetitionsText.getText().toString();
            String dateTime = geDateTime();

            long id = helper.insertGenoflexiuni(dateTime, weight, sets, repetitions);
            if (id > 0)
                System.out.println("Succes MADAFAKAAAAA");
            else
                System.out.println("Failed miserably");

            populateListView();
        }
    });


}

private void populateListView(){
    Cursor cursor = helper.getAllGenoflexiuni();
    String[] campuri = {HelperOwner.DataBaseHelper.DATE_TIME, HelperOwner.DataBaseHelper.GREUTATE_EXERCITIU, HelperOwner.DataBaseHelper.NUMBER_SETURI, HelperOwner.DataBaseHelper.NUMBER_REPETITIONS};
    int[] id = {R.id.dateView, R.id.weightViewItem, R.id.setsViewItem, R.id.repetitionsViewItem};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.inregistrare_exercitiu,cursor,campuri,id,0);
    listView.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

}
```

}

Comment: could you please point out the specific line where it is giving the exception

Comment: Cursor cursor = helper.getAllGenoflexiuni();

Comment: check if helper is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten to initialize **helper** instance, on that you're trying to call `getAllGenoflexiuni()` and change `getBaseContext()` to `Genoflexiuni.this`

Comment: I initialized it now and the exception persists

Comment: Changed the line of the cause   myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.inregistrare_exercitiu,cursor,campuri,id,0);
    listView.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

Comment: it passed the helper.get...() line

Comment: it is still NullPointerException? try to debug and check all arguments you're passing to CursorAdapter's constructor in that case

Comment: Yea is the same exception, ok i will

Comment: What is your `com.example.george.myfirstaplication.Genoflexiuni` class is? Activity?

Comment: try to change `getBaseContext()` with `Genoflexiuni.this`.